# compact injection

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces

Put:

$D=\{u\in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})| x^{\alpha}D^{\beta}_{x}u\in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n}), \forall \alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{N}^{m}:|\alpha|+|\beta|\leq 2 \}$

Why $D \hookrightarrow L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ with compact injection?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which part are you having difficulty with? The compactness, or the injectiveness? Where do you get stuck when you try to prove these yourself?

Comment: I need the compacntess

Comment: OK, so what is your norm on $D$? To discuss compactness of a linear map we need something like a norm on the domain and the codomain of the map

Comment: I use the norm $\|u\|_{D}=\|u\|_{2}+\| x^{\alpha}D^{\beta}_{x}u\|_{2}$,

Comment: i want to prove that the operator $T=-\Delta_{(\mathbb{R}^{n})}+|X|^{2}$ where $X=(x_{1},\dots,x_{n})$ and $|X|^{2}=x^{2}_{1}+\dots+x^{2}_{n}$ with domain $D$ has a resolvent compat. so, i need to prove $D \hookrightarrow L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$  with compact injection.

Comment: OK, so what techniques do you know for checking if a linear map between two Hilbert spaces is compact?

Comment: i use just the definition